# Is there any way to mark a *folder* as watched in XBMC/Raspbmc?

Tags: raspbmc, kodi

I know that you can mark the *contents* of a folder as watched by bringing up the context menu for it and selecting `Mark as watched`, but is there any way to mark the folder *itself* as watched so that the checkmark will appear beside it?

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be a way to do it (full disclosure: I haven't verified it, yet).

### Background

XBMC uses `.nfo` files to track playcount and other statistics (as well as to display thumbnails, descriptions aso.). It also has a mechanism to easily migrate your play settings (from another machine).

### Solution 1

As [described here](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=Import-export_library), there is a way to import an "exported" library (containing also the watched state). So, you could do this:

1. export your library
2. manually/programmatically mark desired (folder) entries as watched
3. import the library

   NB: you have to change the XBMC setting `importwatchedstate` (in [advancedsettings.xml](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=Advancedsettings.xml)) to `true`.

### Solution 2 (easier!)

But, I believe it's even easier to do it directly with `.nfo` file. Here's a hack which (I believe) could work:

1. create an empty `tvshow.nfo` file in the folder you wish to mark as watched

   > The filename of the NFO should be *tvshow.nfo* (Exact, NOT the name of
   >   the actual TV show) and it should be in the root folder of the TV
   >   show.
2. add [this data](http://pastebin.com/KGvVUi80) to the file (most importantly, the `playcount` > 0)

   (Also, you could try removing the `lastplayed` setting as it could be redundant.)

Source: http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=NFO_files/tvshows

Let me know if it works! :)

Comment: I tried Solution 2 both with and without the `lastplayed` setting, but it didn't work :( I'll have to wait another day to try out Solution 1, but if anyone does it before me, let me know here!

Comment: Maybe try with a full tvshow.nfo? Like this: http://pastebin.com/N8aeTddq